# Is it possible to show the gem bullet's aleter only when User.id == 1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-bullet

I'm using the gem called "bullet" https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet
This help to avoid N + 1 problem.

I'd like to use this in production mode with my account(User.id==1)
Is it possible?

I've coded this in /config/environments/production.rb
but the alert pops up whoever the users access.

```
  config.after_initialize do
    Bullet.enable = true 
    Bullet.alert = true 
    Bullet.bullet_logger = true 
    Bullet.console = true 
    Bullet.rails_logger = true 
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know, but you should copy the production database to your local host and try it there, if you dont have enough testing data..

Usually its not recommended to run development gems in production.

==

You can show the bullet output only in the bullet log files (this is not related to user on, but to all users in general):

```
  config.after_initialize do
    Bullet.enable = true 
    Bullet.alert = false 
    Bullet.bullet_logger = true 
    Bullet.console = false 
    Bullet.rails_logger = false 
  end
```

Afterwards you can watch the output in the bullet.log file

Comment: Is it impossible to run on production?

Comment: not impossible, but not recommended.. in production you should only have gems which you really need for your website.

Comment: So if you want to use bullet, i recommend to import your userdata to your local database and run it there.

Comment: what about only when User.id==1 in production mode? Can you show me the way?